# Swift 3/AV Foundation - trouble setting delegate with setsamplebufferdelegate

Tags: ios, swift3, avfoundation

Im having trouble with setsamplebufferdelegate. One of the parameters is a dispatch queue and im not sure what I should be feeding it. Ive tried a few things but it doesnt seem to be working, and as a result captureOutput is not being called because the delegate is not being set.

```
let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)

    videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)

    if videoOutput.sampleBufferDelegate != nil {
        print("buffer delegate set")
    }
```

the print statement is not being called nor is the delegate method captureOutput

ive also tried

```
  videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
```

and

```
videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.background)
```

Im very shaky on dispatch queues right now, and really have no deep understanding. Im not sure if the problem is stemming from misuse of the queues or something else. This is being called in viewDidLoad right now.

*edit - yes I am adding the output to the capture sessions in viewDidLoad

```
 DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

        if self.captureSession.canAddOutput(self.videoOutput) {
            self.captureSession.addOutput(self.videoOutput)
            print("added video output to capture session")
        }

        self.captureSession.startRunning()
    }
```

and can confirm this code runs as expected

Comment: are you adding the `videoOutput` to the capture session?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman yes

Comment: Have you added an `AVCaptureDeviceInput` to your session?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman yes the whole thing is setup correctly. right now its just a live video feed from the front camera that is displayed and functions as expected, except for this.

Comment: Can you put a small project up on github that reproduces the problem & link it here?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman the whole project is very small right now, ill just put it up. Its basically just experimenting with camera stuff. here u go https://github.com/rpcarson/MagicMirror  its all in the VC right now